# Rspec: Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) and undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I get the following error in

Q1. Blackjack #score individual cards scores `"two"` as 2

```
 Failure/Error: expect(score(["two"])).to eq(2)

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
 # ./questions/question_1.rb:78:in `score'
 # ./spec/question_1_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

for every number
question_1.rb

My code:

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end

def move
  @hand = Array.new
  is_stick = false
  while is_stick == false
    puts "hit or stick"
    call = gets.chomp
    if call == "hit"
      @hand.push(random_card())
      score()
      puts "Score so far: " + @total.to_s
    elsif call == "stick"
      is_stick = true
    end
  end
end

def score # Line 78
  @total = 0
  @hand.each do # Line 80
    puts @values
    @total += @values[card]
  end
  @total
end

def run_game
  move()
  if @total <= 21
    puts "You scored: " + @total.to_s
  else
    puts "You busted with: " + @total.to_s
  end
end

@values = {
  "two" => 2,
  "three" => 3,
  "four" => 4,
  "five" => 5,
  "six" => 6,
  "seven" => 7,
  "eight" => 8,
  "nine" => 9,
  "ten" => 10,
  "jack" => 10,
  "queen" => 10,
  "king" => 10,
  "ace" => 11
}
```

This is the rspec file I'm using, whichhis is part of a challenge can't be changed:

```
require_relative "../questions/question_1"
require "mastery_answer_code_quality"

describe "Q1. Blackjack" do
  describe "#random_card" do
    it "returns all the cards in the suit" do
      expect_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:rand).with(13).and_return(0)
      expect(random_card).to eq("two") # Does this for each card
    end
  end

  describe "#move" do
    context "user inputs hit" do
      let (:user_input) { "hit\n" }

      it 'returns `"hit"`' do
        allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:gets).and_return(user_input)
        expect(move).to eq("hit")
      end
    end

    context "user inputs stick" do
      let (:user_input) { "stick\n" }

      it 'returns `"stick"`' do
        allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:gets).and_return(user_input)
        expect(move).to eq("stick")
      end
    end

    context "user inputs blah and then a valid move" do
      let (:user_input) { ["blah\n", "hit\n"] }

      it 'returns valid move (`"hit"`)' do
        allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:gets).and_return(*user_input)
        expect(move).to eq("hit")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#score" do
    describe "individual cards" do
      it 'scores `"two"` as 2' do
        expect(score(["two"])).to eq(2) # does this for each card
      end
    end

    describe "adding up card scores" do
      it 'scores `"two"`, `"jack"` and `"ace"` as 23' do
        expect(score(["two", "jack", "ace"])).to eq(23)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#run_game" do
    describe "showing score so far as game is played" do
      let (:user_input) { ["hit\n",
                           "hit\n",
                           "stick\n"] }

      let (:expected_output) { ["Score so far: 7",
                                "Score so far: 17"].join("\n.*") }

      it "`puts`es scores for two hits" do
        srand(1)
        set_user_input_and_check_expected_output
      end
    end

    describe "`puts`ing outcome of game" do
      context "player takes too many cards and busts" do
        let (:user_input) { ["hit\n",
                             "hit\n",
                             "hit\n",
                             "stick\n"] }

        let (:expected_output) { "You busted with: 28\n" }

        it "`puts`es You busted with: 28" do
          srand(1)
          set_user_input_and_check_expected_output
        end
      end

      context "player doesn't take too many cards" do
        let (:user_input) { ["hit\n",
                             "hit\n",
                             "stick\n"] }

        let (:expected_output) { "You scored: 17\n" }

        it "`puts`es You scored: 17" do
          srand(1)
          set_user_input_and_check_expected_output
        end
      end
    end

    def set_user_input_and_check_expected_output
      allow_any_instance_of(Object)
        .to receive(:gets).and_return(*user_input)

      expect { run_game }
        .to output(/#{expected_output}/m).to_stdout
    end
  end

  it "has acceptable code quality" do
    code_quality = MasteryAnswerCodeQuality.build(__FILE__)
    expect(code_quality.acceptable?).to(eq(true), code_quality.problems)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your error is coming from this line `@total += @values card`. It's because `@values` is a hash, and to access hash elements you would use `[]` on the hash. You're calling `@values` like it's a method. I don't know exactly what code you need to put there - the test is passing an array as an argument to the method, and that doesn't seem like it will work with the code, but that's what you should look at

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please don't include unrelated code (like all the other tests). It's also helpful to point out where the error is actually happening so we don't have to count lines.

Comment: The error message you posted *cannot possibly* be caused by the code you posted. According to the error message, the error is occurring on line 78 of `question_1.rb`, but *there is no line 78* in the code you posted. *Please* make sure that the code and the error you post are *actually* representative of your problem. Also, please make sure that they are a *minimal* example of your problem. Does it really take more than 10 lines to reproduce your problem? I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Score gets an array as parameter in the specs but your code does not pass it.

You need to use something like this:

```
def score(card) # Line 78
  @total = 0
  @hand.each do # Line 80
    puts @values
    @total += @values[card]
  end
  @total
end
```

`undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` means that an array or hash is nil, which you try to access using []. Unfortunately you don't share a stacktrace (error output containing the line numbers for called methods as you posted for the other ArgumentError). I think that neither @hand nor @values is defined somewhere for the test, see edit at the bottom.

Your code uses a lot of instance variables like `@hand` which are maybe not needed, I'd suggest to use local variables, instead of using those, and return values from methods which can then be used as parameters in other methods.

The specs only call the score method and nothing else .
Therefore neither `@hand`nor `@values` instance variables defined outside the method are available. You'd need to define this in the specs, e.g. by using `instance_variable_set(:@hand, ["three"])` or `instance_variable_set(:@values, { "three" => 3 })` in the tests as shown above.

But as you can't change the predefined specs for the challenge this is not possible I guess. And this would of course subsequently lead to other errors, which need a fix as well. This is maybe the wrong approach though, take little steps to get things green, refactor later.

I have added the lines to set instance variables as a reference in my example below:

````
```
  it 'scores `"three"` as 3' do   
    instance_variable_set(:@hand, ["three"]) 
    instance_variable_set(:@values, { "three" => 3 }) 
    expect(score(["three"])).to eq(3)
  end
```
````

Here's my complete solution, which just runs green, I haven't done any refactorings.

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]
  cards[rand(13)]
end

def move
  case gets.chomp
  when "hit"
    "hit"
  when "stick"
    "stick"
  else
    "hit"
  end
end

def score(cards)
  values = {
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6,
    "seven" => 7,
    "eight" => 8,
    "nine" => 9,
    "ten" => 10,
    "jack" => 10,
    "queen" => 10,
    "king" => 10,
    "ace" => 11
  }
  total = 0
  current_result = 0
  cards.each do |card|
    total += values[card]
    current_result = current_result + values[card]
    puts "Score so far: #{current_result}" 
  end
  total
end

def run_game
  cards = []
  total_score = 0 
  while move == 'hit' && total_score <= 21
    cards.unshift random_card
    total_score = score(cards)
  end

  if total_score <= 21
    puts "You scored: #{total_score}"
  else 
    puts "You busted with: #{total_score}"
  end 
end
```

Comment: yesh thats better thank you, but why doesnt it recognise my hash if its outside of the `score` method. also what do you mean by stacktrace sorry I'm quite new to this.